# Box2d Joints and Collisions

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I'm using **cocos2d-x-3.3** with the **Physics Engine Box2D**.

I've built an application where the sprites just bounce from the wall like the cpp-tests application in `Node: Physics -> Contact Test -> yellow triangles`. This is working fine.

But now, because I want to use non-convex polygons as sprites, I splitted them into multiple polygones and joint them with `PhysicsJointFixed`, which leads to the issue that the sprites are **increasingly slowing down with each collision**. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Do you mean the whole app is slowing down, or the app still runs at 60fps and just the movement of the bodies slows down?